# make function in oracle

Tags: oracle, function

if i have this code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkprima (K NUMBER) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
I NUMBER;
hasil NUMBER;
output NUMBER;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('2 ');
FOR I IN 2..K 
LOOP
    IF MOD(I,2)>0 THEN
        IF I > 7 THEN
            IF MOD(I,3)>0 AND MOD(I,5)>0 AND MOD(I,7)>0 THEN
                hasil:=DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(TO_CHAR(I) || ' ');
        END IF;
        ELSE
            hasil:=DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(TO_CHAR(I) || ' ');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
output:=hasil;
RETURN output;
END checkprima;
/
```

example
if i input select checkprima('20').

i want the output is like this

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19

Comment: in this case, the parameter K should be passed as IN parameter to procedure?

Comment: @drgPP yes . example. exec tes ('20');

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tes (K IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('2 ');
FOR I IN 2..K LOOP
    IF MOD(I,2)>0 THEN
        IF I > 7 THEN
            IF MOD(I,3)>0 AND MOD(I,5)>0 AND MOD(I,7)>0 THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(TO_CHAR(I) || ' ');
            END IF;
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(TO_CHAR(I) || ' ');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
END tes;
```

Call the procedure --> `exec tes(20);`

Comment: error. encountered symbol loop when expecting  one of the following if

Comment: @newbie add END IF; before ELSE.

Comment: success, but the output is not out.

Comment: @newbie if you are using SQLPlus, than the keywork for execution is execute.

Comment: the exec procedure is success . but the output is not out.

Comment: @newbie have you turnet ON the output? If no, do it with SET SERVEROUT ON; command

Comment: how about if i change it  to function?

Comment: @newbie please read the oracle documentation for functions and you will find the answer by yourself. If this code resolved your problem, please mark it as accepted answer.